# How to set initial selection of UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder

I am using Xcode 6 with OS X 10.10.

In my UIViewController I have an Outlet for an UISegmentedControl with two segments:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *cardModeButton;
```

In the IB I marked segment 0 as enabled and selected.

[image: IB Attributes Inspector with Segment 0 Enebled and Selected]

However,

```
self.game.nCardGame = self.cardModeButton.selectedSegmentIndex
```

returns nil.

Trying to set the selection programmatically doesn't help, too.

```
self.cardModeButton.selectedSegmentIndex = 0; // or
[self.cardModeButton setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

In any case the debugger shows that the value is not set.

```
(lldb) po self.cardModeButton.selectedSegmentIndex
<nil>
```

Touching the buttons works as expected.
However, before any button is touched, there should be a well defined initial state. Ho to do that?

Comment: Are you setting self.game.nCardGame = self.cardModeButton.selectedSegmentIndex in the viewController's viewDidLoad method?

Comment: @wildBillMunson No, I din't. It's a card game and the game already is started. After flipping the first card, the selection of the cardMode is checked. This means, at this point of time all classes are already correctly instantiated and variables allocated.

Comment: what is self.game.nCardGame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your breakpoint is in `viewDidLoad` or after, I believe that the debugger may be misleading you.  Since `selectedSegmentIndex` is a NSInteger, the "po" (print object) command **should** give you an error.  It appears to be taking the value zero and treating it as a nil pointer instead.

Use "p (NSInteger)self.cardModeButton.selectedSegmentIndex" to see the value.